# Add string of html <TR> to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've been trying for almost a day!

I have an array of strings of `"<tr>...</tr>"` to add to a Datatables table. But every single way I've tried always results in the whole `[object HTMLTableRowElement]` being *shoved into the 1st column* only.

How am I supposed to do this? Can you help?

What I have so far:

```
var table = $j('#table_view_subs').DataTable();

var fakehtml = '<tr><td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td></tr>';

table.row.add($(fakehtml)).draw();
```

I've tried creating an element with javascript, adding the html, and row.adding that. Also tried a bunch of other stuff, I don't even know x(

Ok, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xez5bcu/1/)!

Comment: Your input data `fakehtml` is a string but in your question you talk about `an array of strings of <tr>...</tr>`.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())? You dont have to supply custom HTML.

Comment: @Xatenev ah yes, but this was just a small demo. I just tried it like this and it's still the same error

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue in a https://jsfiddle.net/ - as it is we can't really help in a good way with your "small demo".

Comment: @Xatenev can't tell you how many times I read that page haha! But I don't get it! It says you can do it with with html tag, js object, and arrays. I tried the 1st two and failed :( The 3rd isn't really possible because I have a variable number of columns

Comment: @Xatenev ok, I'll do that. So in your point of view there's no reason why this code wouldn't work, if everything else was ok?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: It alerts this message: " DataTables warning: table id=table_view_subs - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 12, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the HTML and instead provided an input array for the columns.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vpjmzc6k/

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    const table = $('#table_view_subs').DataTable(),
    input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    table.row.add(input).draw();
} );
```

---

```
<table id="table_view_subs">
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm.. in the array, instead on integers, can I put strings? The '<tr> ... </tr>' strings that I talked about. I tried it, but it ended up putting every column into the 1st one :/

Comment: It started working when I used "table.row.add(input)" rather than "table.row.add($(input))". Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Datatables `row.add()` API function can take a JQuery node as argument. You could something like this:

```
strArray.forEach(function(el){
    table.row.add($(el));
});
table.draw();
```

Assuming strArray is the array of strings, and each string represents a `<tr>` element, this should work.

Comment: I still don't know why this didn't work.. but thank you for the help :)